# EF6 Select with Many to Many relationship

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I am new to EF attempting to retrieve results that require a many to many relationship.

This is the schema
[image]

This is the SQL version of what I'm trying to get with LINQ

```
select v.ID ViewID, ve.Title, ve.VersionID, r.Role, vr.RoleID
from [View] v, Roles r, Versions ve, View_Roles vr
where v.ID = vr.ViewID
and r.ID = vr.RoleID
and ve.ContentStatusID = 2
and ve.ViewID = v.ID
order by r.Role
```

This is the results view of the above
[image]

This is how the View_Roles table is manifested in my context file

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
                .Property(e => e.Role1)
                .IsUnicode(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Views)
                .WithMany(e => e.Roles)
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("View_Roles").MapLeftKey("RoleID").MapRightKey("ViewID"));
```

This is Role.cs

```
public class Role
    {
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Role()
        {
            Users_Roles = new HashSet<Users_Roles>();
            Views = new HashSet<View>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Column("Role")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Role1 { get; set; }

        public bool IsAdminRole { get; set; }

        public int OrderBy { get; set; }

        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Users_Roles> Users_Roles { get; set; }

        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<View> Views { get; set; }
    }
```

This is View.cs

```
[Table("View")]
public class View
{
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public View()
    {
        PermanentRedirects = new HashSet<PermanentRedirect>();
        Users_Roles = new HashSet<Users_Roles>();
        Versions_View = new HashSet<Versions_View>();
        View_Links = new HashSet<View_Links>();
        View_Localized = new HashSet<View_Localized>();
        View1 = new HashSet<View>();
        ViewGroups = new HashSet<ViewGroup>();
        ViewGroups1 = new HashSet<ViewGroup>();
        languages = new HashSet<language>();
        Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

[StringLength(32)]
public string ID { get; set; }

public bool HideFromNavigationOverride { get; set; }

[StringLength(32)]
public string ParentID { get; set; }

public int? ThemeID { get; set; }

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<PermanentRedirect> PermanentRedirects { get; set; }

public virtual Theme Theme { get; set; }

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<Users_Roles> Users_Roles { get; set; }

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<Versions_View> Versions_View { get; set; }

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<View_Links> View_Links { get; set; }

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<View_Localized> View_Localized { get; set; }

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<View> View1 { get; set; }

public virtual View View2 { get; set; }

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<ViewGroup> ViewGroups { get; set; }

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<ViewGroup> ViewGroups1 { get; set; }

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<language> languages { get; set; }

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

}

This is the LINQ I'm attempting but since I don't understand how to use the View_Roles table it isn't getting what I need, certainly.

```
return (
                from v in PagesContext.Versions 
                from r in PagesContext.Roles
                where v.ContentStatusID == 2 && r.IsAdminRole == false
                select new RestrictedPage
                {
                    ViewID = v.ViewID,
                    Title = v.Title,
                    RoleID = r.ID,
                    Role = r.Role1,
                    VersionID = v.VersionID
                }
           ).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you explain more what is the result that you are expecting, why you say that is not getting what you need. The sql query you show is doing a cross join between multiple tables

Comment: The results of the linq query don't include a reference to the View_Roles table so I have no way to filter the results I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way you can achieve what you are trying is doing the following:

```
var query= PagesContext.Versions.Where(ve=>ve.ContentStatusID == 2)
                                .SelectMany(ve=>ve.View.Roles
                                                  .Where(r=>r.IsAdminRole == false)
                                                  .Select(r=> new RestrictedPage
                                                                   {
                                                                     ViewID = ve.ViewID,
                                                                     Title = ve.Title,
                                                                     RoleID = r.ID,
                                                                     Role = r.Role1,
                                                                     VersionID = ve.VersionID
                                                                   })).ToList();
```

In your case the junction table is not mapped directly, it's hide, so one solution to get the data related you need is using `SelectMany` extension method. First apply the condition to one of the to ends of your query, in my example was `Versions` and then apply `SelectMany`, that is going generate an inner join between both tables and to flatten the result in one collection.

### Update

I think the issue is because Version and `View` are not really related directly in your DB, so you are going to do an explicit inner join:

```
var query= PagesContext.Versions.Where(ve=>ve.ContentStatusID == 2)
                                .Join( PagesContext.Views, ve=>ve.ViewId, v=>v.ID,(ve,v)=>v)
                                .SelectMany(v=>v.Roles
                                                  .Where(r=>r.IsAdminRole == false)
                                                  .Select(r=> new RestrictedPage
                                                                   {
                                                                     ViewID = ve.ViewID,
                                                                     Title = ve.Title,
                                                                     RoleID = r.ID,
                                                                     Role = r.Role1,
                                                                     VersionID = ve.VersionID
                                                                   })).ToList();
```

Comment: In this instance, ".SelectMany(ve => ve.Roles", ve.Roles is telling me 'Version' does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'Version' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: But according with your configuration you have a collection of `Roles` in your `Views` entity: `.WithMany(e => e.Roles)`, right?

Comment: there are two references, I neglected to add both. modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
                .Property(e => e.Role1)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Views)
                .WithMany(e => e.Roles)
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("View_Roles").MapLeftKey("RoleID").MapRightKey("ViewID"));

Comment: Please share your `View` entity

Comment: No the configurations, the `View` class, your configuration says `Roles` collection exist as part of `View` properties

Comment: public virtual DbSet<View> Views { get; set; }

Comment: I appended the question with more information.  Hopefully it is helpful.

Comment: I was asking about `View` class, not `Role`s. `View` has to have a collection of Roles like:`public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles{ get; set; }
`

Comment: I added the view class

Comment: I don't understand why `ve.Roles` is not recognized because I can see the `Roles` property in your `View` entity

Comment: If you meant to replace View with Versions like this, then the same problem occurs  var query = PagesContext.Versions.Where.

Comment: Question, `Version` is not related directly with any of your tables right?

Comment: Version relates via ViewID

Comment: I think I understand better your model now, check the query, `Version` has to have a `View` property, use that to navigate to `View`, and then you can get access to the `Roles`

Comment: when using this, PagesContext.Views.Where(ve => ve.ContentStatusID == 2), ContentStatusID isn't in Views, do I need a join here somehow?

Comment: `PagesContext.Versions.Where`, please, take a second look the query

Comment: in this case, .SelectMany(ve => ve.View.Roles, View becomes the problem

Comment: But, that's why was my previous question about if `Version` was related with any other table, I thought is was related with `View`, if that is the case then `Version` class has to have a `Version` property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189951/discussion-between-john-kinane-and-octavioccl).

Comment: I would sincerely appreciate some resource suggestions for learning linq syntax like you've presented here. SQL is easy for me but I don't know how to comprehend linq syntax for complex queries.

Comment: First, you need to know there are two syntax: query syntax and method syntax. I use both, for you is going to be easier to learn query syntax because is closer to sql . About resources, for me this was one of the best: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/

Comment: Examples of how to use the methods: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b